# Copyright character get defaulted to "?" when written to a file in INFORMATICA

Tags: utf-8, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange, informatica-cloud

Please find the below details:

Source: Table in Netezza db

Target: Flat file generated in unix

Informatica 9.6 version

Issue: Copyright character gets defaulted to "?" when written to the file.

Thing tried from my end:

The **target code page** is set to UTF-8

The **source connection string** is having the code page set to UTF-8

The **"File properties"** at the session is having code page set to UTF-8

The code page of the repository is ISO 8859-1 Western European. ( If i change this to UTF-8, will it work?)(How will it affect the other workflows which are using "MS windows Latin" as the codepage)

I tried to run the workflow with the above configuration, but the file which got generated still had "?" character instead of "Copyright" character.

Also, i tried to give "ISO 8859-1 Western European" at all the places mentioned above, but still did not got any luck.

Please Help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Repository code page should be UTF-8 and Integration service should also run in UNICODE mode. It should not impact other mappings using MS Windows Latin, as far as I know.